# ebean query 2 models and render to html

Tags: scala, playframework, ebean

I have setup 2 models in ebean, both work fine when queried separately. Now i need to get into my Show.scala.html fields from both my product & heading models, the product fields work fine but I also need the DateOrder from heading, but I am getting a compilation error of value DateOrder is not a member of object models.Heading, please help

My Models

```
package models;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="Heading")
public class Heading extends Model {


    @Id

    @Column(name="JobKeyID")
    public Integer JobKeyID;
    @Constraints.MaxLength(50)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="Name")
    public String Name;
    @Column (name="JobNumber", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR")
    public String JobNumber;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="SellingPriceIncTax")
    public Integer SellingPriceIncTax;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="DateOrder")
    public Date DateOrder;
    @Column(name="CustomerID")
    public Integer CustomerID;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "heading", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Product> product;

    public static Finder<Integer, Heading> find = new Finder<>(Heading.class);


}

package models;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;
import io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonList;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product extends Model {


    @Id

    @Column(name = "ItemKeyID")
    public Integer ItemKeyID;
    @Constraints.MaxLength(50)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    public String ProductName;
    @Column(name = "ItemNumber")
    public Integer ItemNumber;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "DesignName")
    public String DesignName;
    @Column(name = "JobKeyID")
    public  Integer JobKeyID;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="JobKeyID")
    public Heading heading;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    public List<Information> information;

    public static Finder<Integer, Product> find = new Finder<>(Product.class);

}
```

My Controller

```
   public Result show(Integer id){
                    List<Product> products = Ebean.find(Product.class)
                            .fetch("heading")
                            .where().eq("JobKeyID",id)
                    .setFirstRow(0)
                    .setMaxRows(10)
                    .findList();
            return ok(show.render(products)) ;
    }
```

and my scala.html

```
@(products : List[Product])


@Layout("All Books") {
    <h1> All Books</h1>
    @for(product <- products) {
            <a class="btn btn-link" href="@routes.BooksController.specinfo(product.JobKeyID, product.ItemKeyID)">@product.ProductName</a>
            <p> Design Name : @product.DesignName</p>
        <p> Order Date : @Heading.DateOrder</p>


            <img src ="@routes.ImagesController.getImage("419326-1.svg")"/>


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get field DateOrder via class, but it's not a static member. I believe it's the cause. If I understood your intention correctly, you should replace `@Heading.DateOrder` with `@product.heading.DateOrder`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice that means I don't get any error but the DateOrder is not showing any data from within the show page when i run it. I have tried the other fields from my heading model and the only one I can get to show anything is the JobKeyID which is the field I am using to link the 2 models. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Sorry that did work fine I had removed the fetch line from when trying to solve the issue myself earlier, thanks for your help